# Calculating the cost of Block Nested Loop Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to calculate the cost of the (most efficient) block nested loop join in terms of NDPR (number of disk page reads). Suppose you have a query of the form:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM county JOIN mcd
ON count.state_code = mcd.state_code
AND county.fips_code = mcd.fips_code
WHERE county.state_code = @NO
```

where @NO is substituted for a state code on each execution of the query.

I know that I can derive the NPDR using: `NPDR(R x S) = |Pages(R)| + Pages(R) / B - 2 . |P ages(S)|`

(where the smaller table is used as the outer in order to produce less page reads. Ergo:
R = county, S = mcd).

I also know that Page size = 2048 bytes

```
Pointer = 8 byte
Num. rows in mcd table = 35298
Num. rows in county table = 3141
Free memory buffer pages B = 100
Pages(X) = (rowsize)(numrows) / pagesize
```

**What I am trying to figure out is how the "`WHERE county.state_code = @NO`" affects my cost?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is NDPR (or NPDR)? I'm guessing something like number of dirty page reads from the formula.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have specified that. NPDR = Number of page disk reads.

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of observations regarding the formula you wrote:

- I'm not sure why it you write "B - 2" instead of "B - 1". From a theoretical perspective, you need a single buffer page to read in relation S (you can do it by reading one page at a time).
- Make sure you use all the brackets. I would write the formula as: 
   `NPDR(R x S) = |Pages(R)| + |Pages(R)| / (B-2) * |Pages(S)|`
- The all numbers in the formula would need to be rounded up (but this is nitpicking).
- The explanation for the generic BNLJ formula:

  - You read in as many tuples from the smaller relation (R) as you can keep in memory (B-1 or B-2 pages worth of tuples).
  - For each group of B-2 pages worth of tuples, you then have to read the whole S relation ( |Pages(S)|) to perform the join for that particular range of relation R.
  - At the end of the join, relation R is read exactly one time and relation S is read  as many times as we filled the memory buffer, namely `|Pages(R)| / (B-2)` times.

**Now the answer:**

- In your example a selection criteria is applied to relation R (table Country in this case). This is the `WHERE county.state_code = @NO` part of the query. Therefore, the generic formula does not apply directly.
- When reading from relation R (i.e., table Country in your example), we can discard all the non-qualifying tuples that do not match the selection criteria. Assuming that there are 50 states in the USA and that all states have the same number of counties, only 2% of the tuples in table Country qualify on average and need to be stored in memory. This reduces the number of iteration of the inner loop of the join (i.e., the number of times we need to scan relation S / table mcs). The 2% number is obviously just the expected average and will change depending on the actual given state.
- The formula for your problem therefore becomes: 
   `NPDR(R x S) = |Pages(County)| + |Pages(County)| / (B - 2) * |Counties in state @NO| / |Rows in table County| * |Pages(Mcd)|`